# IPS4.1 pop up text translation (invision power board 4.1/IPS 4.1) howto?

Tags: php, ipb, invision-power-board

Have problem with translation IPS4.1
Alert buttons have no next (translated from Yes, Cancel)
in js alert buttons.

[image]
[image]

Can your please help me understood where are come from.

i add yes term, js=1 and js=0 to db.
Adding few images js & look af alert popup.

Comment: Seems like the `lang` is not set for the buttons

Comment: I dont know, that was need to reload cache, only after this JS elements like buttons & select translates. From Admin panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know that was need to reload cache, 
only after this JS elements like buttons & select translates. 
From IPS4 Admin panel.